# how to get the context following a Keyword search in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the context following the "RESPONSIBILITIES". But I cannot finish it. How can I get the context without tag?

```html
<strong>RESPONSIBILITIES:</strong>

<ul>

<li>Reach or exceed assigned sales goals</li>

<li>Implement sales strategies</li>

<li>Develop and execute a cold calling strategy to target prospects</li>

<li>Mine existing and prospective clients for referral business</li>

<li>Establish and maintain strong relationships, with both internal partners and external customers</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: You mean you want to get the text from the `<ul>` following the `<strong>` tag?

Answer (score 0):

Following should work:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
print soup.find('strong', text=re.compile('RESPONSIBILITIES:').find_next_sibling('ul').text
```